# NameError: name 'beam' is not defined in <lambda>

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm running a beam pipeline in google dataflow. For a long time it used to work good with no issues. Now, and without changing anything in code, when I run it, I submit it to google dataflow, I get this error:

```
wrapper = lambda x: [fn(x)]
File "read_from_gcs.py", line 391, in <lambda>
NameError: name 'beam' is not defined [while running 'Covert to Row-ptransform-2054']
```

I already imported apachea_beam as beam (as I use it to call all transformations)
The error is pointing to the following code:

```
schema_for_dedup = (
            distinct_without_chain | 'Filter nulls' >> beam.Filter(lambda r: r['key1'] != None and r['key2'] != None and r['key3'] != None)
            | 'Covert to Row' >> beam.Map(lambda val: beam.Row(
                             k= val['k'],
                             k2= val['k2'],
                             ))

        )
```

The weird thing is when I run the job locally, it runs successfully with no issues. But when I submit it to the dataflow with DataflowRunner it shows these errors. I'm using apache-beam 2.32.0

Does google changed something in the infrastructure of dataflow these days? How can it be working few days before, and working good on my local computer but producing this error now?

Have anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: When I changed the region to europe-west4 instead of europe-west3, I got this new error: TypeError: '_UnwindowedValues' object is not subscriptable pointing to the lambda function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the `__main__` module? That could be the reason `beam` is not defined in your lambda when running on a remote machine. You could try passing the `--save_main_session` pipeline option or put all your code in another module that you import in your main module or put your imports inside a function e.g.

```
def run():
  import apache_beam as beam
  [build your pipline as normal]
```

As for the second error, europe-west4 vs. europe-west3 shouldn't matter, but `TypeError: '_UnwindowedValues'` indicates that you're trying to use `[index]` with the result of a GroupBykey which is generally only an iterable, not a list (as it may not fit into memory). Instead of

```
def process_gbk_results(key, values):
  # do something with values[0]

input | beam.GroupByKey() | beam.MapTuple(process_gbk_results)
```

do something like

```
def process_gbk_results(key, values):
  for value in values:
    # do something with value
```

or

```
def process_gbk_results(key, values):
  # do something with next(iter(values))
```

or

```
def process_gbk_results(key, values):
  values = list(values)
  # do something with values[0]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Regarding the '_UnwindowedValues' I tried them all, and all of them work good on my local computer, but once I submit them to Dataflow I get the _UnwindowedValues error. How could it work on my local computer and fail in dataflow since it's the same version of apache beam?

Comment: next(iter(values)) did the trick thank you. But still I couldn't understand how things are working properly in local but it fails in dataflow. Because it's hard to debug on google dataflow

Comment: This is because on the local runner everything is in memory, so the result is literally a list rather than a reference to a distributed remote store. We should probably "degrade" the local runner so it doesn't work there either.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/15662